# Activerecord :include additional conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do you specify a JOIN ON clause in ActiveRecord?

When using the :include parameter to the ActiveRecord.find method, the created SQL uses the JOIN operation with the ON clause of foreign key=primary key. For example:

```
A.find(:include => :B)
```

results in

```
select ... from A 
  left outer join B on B.a_id=A.id
```

Now to my example:

```
A.find(:include => { :B => { :include => :C } } )
```

results in:

```
select ... from A 
  left outer join B on B.a_id=A.id 
  left outer join C on C.b_id=B.id
```

But, I only want some of the records in C, but if none are found then I still want A and B

This does not work

```
A.find(:include => { :B => { :include => :C } },
  :condition => "C.rec<10" )
```

Because that results in:

```
select ... from A 
  left outer join B on B.a_id=A.id 
  left outer join C on C.b_id=B.id
  where C.rec<10
```

How do I instruct AcriveRecord to create a query like this?

```
select ... from A 
  left outer join B on B.a_id=A.id 
  left outer join C on C.b_id=B.id and C.rec<10
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to add an ON clause with association methods.

For your example, the easiest way to eager-load only some records in C is to define an association with conditions in B.  (See the "Eager loading of associations" section of this [ActiveRecord::Associations API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).)

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cs
    has_many :cs_with_rec_less_than_10, :class_name => 'C', :conditions => ['rec < 10']
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You can call:

```
A.includes(:bs => :cs_with_rec_less_than_10)
```

This will generate 3 queries, one to each table, rather than joining them in 1 query.  For example, if A and B each contain 2 records with IDs 1 and 2:

```
SELECT "as".* FROM "as"
SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE ("bs".a_id IN (1,2))
SELECT "cs".* FROM "cs" WHERE ("cs".b_id IN (1,2) AND (rec < 10))
```

If it's important to make a single query using left joins I would write the query manually, execute it with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, and handle the result directly.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not the most Railistic solution, but I find it handy when I am in despair of searching for Railstic sulutions.

I trust you can figure out what to do with below example and hope you can find it useful somehow.

```
@visits = Visit.select("v.*, c.*" ).
  where("u.id = ?", session[:user_id]).
  joins( %{ as v inner join customers as c on (v.customer_id = c.id)
      inner join businesses as b on (v.business_id = b.id)
      inner join managers as m on (b.manager_id = m.id)
      inner join users as u on (m.user_id = u.id)
      } ).
  order(' v.created_at DESC')
```